# Overlay image programmatically

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement a gridView with images, a transparent gradient overlay, and a textView, so the text will always be readable no matter what the image colors are. I fail to add the overlay and TextView. I read in another question, that RelativeLayouts are the way to go for the overlay, and then set the RelativeLayout background for the gradient XML file. Here is what I have so far.

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public GridViewAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        RelativeLayout gradient;
        TextView textView;
        DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
        int screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(screenWidth / 2, screenWidth / 2));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            gradient = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
            gradient.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gridview_gradient_image_overlay));
            gradient.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(screenWidth / 2, screenWidth / 2));

        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            gradient = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.dog, R.drawable.cat,
            R.drawable.horse, R.drawable.bunny,
            R.drawable.fish, R.drawable.hamster,
            R.drawable.hedgehog, R.drawable.bird,
            R.drawable.turtle, R.drawable.goat
    };
}
```

And this is the gradient XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#33000000"
        android:centerColor="#11000000"
        android:endColor="#00000000"
        android:angle="90"
        android:dither="true"
        />
</shape>
```

XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rlGradient"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gridview_gradient_image_overlay">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGridViewAnimal"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is a very common question

Comment: Post your XML layout, this is a z-order issue

Comment: There you go. just added.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the XML-based z-order, just invoke the method [`bringToFront()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront())

```
// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //...
    textView.bringToFront();
    return imageView;
}
```